# How to update yellowstone tablet or work with an older sdk?

Tags: sdk, google-project-tango

We have a yellowstone tablet at work and I wanted to work with it. I explored the examples given by google, but impossible to use them because of the outdated tango core. I've tried to update, restore to factory, use a USA google account (We are in France), and nothing seems to change.

Did I miss something ?

In case I cannot update it, it is possible to use an older SDK to continue to work with?

Answer (score 0):

I've been going through these same issues. They have discontinued updates for the Yellowstone tablet (pretty sure that's the same as the Tango Development Kit), and I also could not find an older SDK to work with. I emailed them this morning for some help and I'll let you know what they say. Couldn't hurt to email them yourself too, though, so they know it's a real problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Which email did you use to contact them ? I'll send a message too, in hope to get this sdk ! If I have news too, I'll contact you back.

Comment: I used tango-help@google.com. They replied back and said that the email is only for troubleshooting, and to look on the Google+ and StackOverflow communities for answers. They said "other developers have found useful workarounds". I haven't found those workarounds yet, but I'm also doing this Tango stuff on the side, so it's not a priority for me

Comment: Looks like everything works fine (for now) if you roll back to the "G" tango core. I am trying to find out what version number that is, and how to get back to it, but the Google+ developer group seems to be more helpful on this topic than stackoverflow